# "Ambiguous column name" in SQLite using update and set

Tags: sql, sqlite, join, sql-update, ambiguous

First of all, I'm sorry because I know there are many questions regarding "Ambiguous column name" error here in Stack but I'm really newbie in SQL and doing my first queries using SQLite I found this error. After analyzing other several questions I didn't find a solution for my problem (maybe, it's here for sure but I couldn't find) and this is:
When I use **update**, **set** and doing any operation such as the example I put... Well, the error appears and I don't understand the problem. I tried some options but nothing.

```
update nota
set subtot=cantidad*precio
from nota inner join producto on producto.clave_prod=nota.clave_prod1;
```

"Cantidad" column is on table called "nota" and "precio" column is on table called "producto" and both are linked between foreign keys.

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: Can you add some sample data. See [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Get into the good habbit of using *table* and *column* aliases. If both tables contain the same column - I have no idea which column you are using - and neither does the query engine, hence the error.

Comment: The engine doesn't know which table `cantidad` and/or `precio` belong to. Prepend the table name to each one and problem solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax is wrong.
There is no need to refer to the updated table after `FROM` and the `ON` clause must be replaced with a `WHERE` clause.

This is the correct syntax (if your SQLite version is 3.33.0+) for a join-like [`UPDATE`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_update.html#update_from) satement:

```
update nota
set subtot = nota.cantidad * producto.precio -- subtot must not be qualified with nota.
from producto 
where producto.clave_prod = nota.clave_prod1;
```

or with aliases:

```
update nota AS n
set subtot = n.cantidad * p.precio -- subtot must not be qualified with n.
from producto AS p
where p.clave_prod = n.clave_prod1;
```